# what is the correct mime type for vcalendar

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mime-types, nfc, vcalendar

I'm trying to create vcalendar for nfc tags,but what is the correct mime type? It should be something like this

> WindowsMime:WriteTag.Text/vcalendar
>
> WindowsMime:WriteTag.Text/x-vcalendar

but when I try to read the tag, the prompt message is "Sorry your phone can't recognise this type of file"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The RFC mime type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545) is `text/calendar` rather than `text/vcalendar`, does that work?

How are you creating the file? There is a BSD-licensed iCal class library for .NET called [DDay.Ical](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/)

Comment: the phone downloaded an app - "iCalendar Import", and now its working

Answer (score 3):

The type for vCalendar seems to be `text/x-vcalendar` (source: [original standard](http://www.imc.org/pdi/vcal-10.txt).)

For *iCalendar* (the newer format), the answer is `text/calendar` (source: [RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545)).

iCalendar is essentially v2.0 of the vCalendar format. If v2.0 of a format introduces a new MIME type for the new version of the format, it has never been clear to me whether the older versions of the format also get that new MIME type. The IANA registry doesn't help in clarifying things either.