# Can I share a calendar entry via NFC without starting my app on the destination phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, nfc

Is it possible to create an NFC message that will create a calendar entry on the destination phone, without requiring my app to be installed on the destination phone?

For the moment, I've implemented it by using a custom protocol URI, but I'd like this to work even when the destination phone does not have my app installed. It would be even better if it could work on an Android destination.

Comment: And what would be your question for us?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this on any phone if I am not mistaken. NFC messages at the end of the day are just bytes being transferred from one mobile device to another. If the destination device does not know how (and most of them do NOT have a build in handler for calendar event) to parse that message in order to open a native application what you are trying to do will not work.

Even if you get an NFC reader and read an NFC message design for that purpose and then recreate this in your application it will NOT be universal; meaning it will not work on any device, especially on different OS devices.

Again this is what I know so far. Don't take this for granted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to store a vcalendar item on a tag to see whether/how a phone reacts to this?

`text/x-vcalendar` or `text/calendar`

might be the right format to use for the NDEF record. See also [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746872/what-is-the-correct-mime-type-for-vcalendar).

If this would not work, you might write an app that takes intents from such calendar data and sends it to the calendar app on the phone (however I don't know how that step would work).