# Generate file object from content using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this file data

```
const ics = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n' +
'VERSION:2.0\n' +
'CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\n' +
'METHOD:PUBLISH\n' +
'END:VCALENDAR\n';
```

i want to generate file object

where fileBody is `ics` data

```
convert(fileBody,filename)
{
      let fileContent=this.dataURLtoFile('data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(fileBody),filename);
}

dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
  console.log('dataurl',dataurl);
  var arr = dataurl.split(","),
    mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
    bstr = atob(arr[1]),
    n = bstr.length,
    u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

  while (n--) {
    u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
  }

  return new File([u8arr], filename, { type: mime });
}
```

but this is not converting to file

Comment: WHats the file format you are trying to convert to?

Comment: @GetSet i want to convert it to ics file data, and use file for further processing

Comment: From cursory research on ICS file format, it appears you *already* have it in that format. Are you looking to have methods that work on ICS? If so, and likely you would want to, then why reinvent the wheel... find a library that does so.

Comment: @GetSet i checked library in angular but it was not supporting my current angular version that's why trying to generate, contents are being generated i want it to convert to a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just passing the string to [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) or [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), with mime type `text/calendar` for `.ics` file format (see: [Common MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)):

```
convert(fileBody,filename)
{
     let fileContent=this.dataURLtoFile('text/calendar;charset=utf-8', fileBody, filename);
         
}

dataURLtoFile(mime, data) {

  return new File([data], filename, { type: mime } );
}
```

But if you just want to download the file, you can just use data url with `ics` string as the content:

```
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = 'data:text/calendar,' + encodeURIComponent(fileBody);
link.download = 'calendar.ics';
link.click();
```

Comment: Thanks i want only file can you pls confirm for ics the type will be text/calendar

Comment: yes: [what is the correct mime type for vcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746872/what-is-the-correct-mime-type-for-vcalendar), and _`.ics  iCalendar format  text/calendar`_: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

Answer (score -1):

Based on your code snippet, it seems you want to generate a file object from the provided content and filename. Here's a modified version of your code that should work:

```
const ics = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n' +
  'VERSION:2.0\n' +
  'CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\n' +
  'METHOD:PUBLISH\n' +
  'END:VCALENDAR\n';

function convert(fileBody, filename) {
  const fileContent = dataURLtoFile('data:text/calendar;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(fileBody), filename);
  // Use the fileContent as needed
  console.log(fileContent);
}

function dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
  const arr = dataurl.split(",");
  const mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
  const bstr = atob(arr[1]);
  const n = bstr.length;
  const u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    u8arr[i] = bstr.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  return new File([u8arr], filename, { type: mime });
}

// Example usage:
convert(ics, 'calendar.ics');
```

In this code, the convert function takes the fileBody (ICS data) and filename as parameters. It generates a file object using the dataURLtoFile function, which converts the data URL to a File object.

You can now use the generated File object (fileContent) as needed, such as uploading it to a server, saving it locally, or sending it via email.

Note that the example usage at the end simply calls the convert function with the provided ics content and a filename of 'calendar.ics'. You can modify the code to suit your specific needs.